# How to fail on boot if an env variable is not set in Rails with anyway_config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, anyway-config

I am currently working with the Rails application which depends on a huge amount of ENV variables.

The problem is when somebody adds a new ENV variable and forgets to notify the team about it, we spend a lot of time debugging errors like `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` in very unexpected contexts.

After some googling, I have found the [Anyway Config:
Keep your Ruby configuration sane](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/anyway-config-keep-your-ruby-configuration-sane) article.

It contains the following principle:

> The application must fail on boot if a system secret is missing or invalid

I really believe we can leverage from it since instead of too generic errors we can have something like `ENV variable #{some_name} is NOT set` before the application is even started.

So, I set up `anyway_config` as in the [Installation guide](https://github.com/palkan/anyway_config#installation).

```rb
gem "anyway_config", "~> 2.0"
```

Run a [generator](https://github.com/palkan/anyway_config#generators):

```sh
rails g anyway:install
```

and created the following config file in the `config/configs` directory.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class CurrentApplicationConfig < ApplicationConfig
  env_prefix 'CURRENT_APPLICATION'

  attr_config :name

  required :name
end
```

After that, when I execute `rails server` without specifying `CURRENT_APPLICATION_NAME` env variable, I expect to receive an error, but it is not raised.

Could somebody explain what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.current_app_config = CurrentApplicationConfig.new

> rails s # error
 
> CURRENT_APPLICATION_NAME=demo rails s # ok
```